# Internet dropping with dual network cards in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have the network setup with 2 nic cards in ubuntu 16.04.

- **ens4** acts as isp,
- **eno1** is for lan.

I am sharing the internet from ens4 to eno1 using firestarter.

here is the output of `ifconfig`

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:3b:e5:27:00:0e  
          inet addr:172.16.0.40  Bcast:172.16.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::de1a:ed2a:763e:c68/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3109124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5627690 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:554205033 (554.2 MB)  TX bytes:7057683260 (7.0 GB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:de400000-de420000 

ens4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:35:0f:f0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.212  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9399:f699:aa8a:54a0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7597294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3872202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9152672957 (9.1 GB)  TX bytes:596864488 (596.8 MB)
```

The `ens4` got ip from main router, by static, and `eno1` gets ip from other `DHCP` server which is connected via a **switch**.

The internet drops down for 5 seconds and comes back, this happens for every 20 to 30 minutes.

This issue is on `eno1` network card mainly.
Internet dropping is verified by using `google sheets`, it shows reconnecting even when it is connected to network.

Previously I shared internet with `iptables`, and now I am using `firestarter` for sharing the internet form one nic card to other. But the issue is same.

here is the output of `route -n`

```
   192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens4
   172.16.0.40     0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eno1.
```

I was unable to figure out what is the reason for the internet drops please help.

Comment: Take a look at `/var/log/syslog`. Is there any event logged that could clarify what happens?

Comment: i could just see the traffic, like this. MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ac:81:12:db:61:b3:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.239 DST=192.168.1.255 LEN=291 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=15928 PROTO=UDP SPT=54915 DPT=54915 LEN=271

Comment: This looks like a firewall entry. Observe, when connection drops and see if there are lines in the log file saying that the network connection was broken. From what I read, I would say the problem is not in your computer,  but rather somewhere else.

Comment: thanks, i will look into that and what might be the reason for that, any configuration issues or other , any idea.

Comment: and by the way i don't see any drop or broken in that syslog.

Comment: my mtu size is 1500, does it depends on internet drop/ speed issues.

Comment: This looks like a possible issue with your router, or how your ISP is delivering the connection. Are you in the UK with FTTC or is this DSL
IF your using FTTC with a ISP router, it could be this I had massive issues, Then I got off fleabay a old openreach Modem, this gives me pppoe and it works perfect I get a drop every 10 days for about 2 mins when the ISP forces my connection to update.